# MongoDB Installation error. what is solution for this error?

Tags: mongodb

what is solution for this error.
I want to install MongoDB in Mac with home-brew but this error in terminal

❯ brew tap mongodb/brew
❯ brew install mongodb-community
Error: No such file or directory - /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/linked/mongodb-community

I want to install MongoDB...

Comment: Try with `brew tap mongodb/brew` -> `brew update` -> `brew install mongodb-community@6.0`

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the MongoDB Community Server version suitable for your Mac from the official website: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/community.
2. Install MongoDB by double-clicking the downloaded .pkg file.

[image]

Note: To run MongoDB as a service on macOS, refer to the official MongoDB documentation on setting up launchd: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#configure-launchd-to-start-mongodb-automatically.

Comment: ❯ mkdir -p /data/db
mkdir: /data: Read-only file system

Comment: what is this error?.....